# Sumar valores de una columna solo para un grupo de terminado de filas, sí cumple una condición determinada MySQL

Tags: mysql

Necesito sumar los valores de la columna : measurement_price_total_awarded, sólo sí, tienen el mismo id_measurement.

[image: example]
`` SELECT pm.id, pm.id_measurement, m.measurement_price_total_awarded FROM purchase_measurement AS pm INNER JOIN measurement AS m on m.id = pm.id_measurement INNER JOIN purchase AS p on p.id = pm.id_purchase WHERE p.id_purchase_status = 6 ORDER BY `pm`.`id_measurement` DESC; ``

he intentado  hacer esto :

`` SELECT SUM (m.measurement_price_total_awarded) FROM purchase_measurement AS pm INNER JOIN measurement AS m on m.id = pm.id_measurement INNER JOIN purchase AS p on p.id = pm.id_purchase WHERE p.id_purchase_status = 6 ORDER BY `pm`.`id_measurement` DESC; ``

y me suma todo los valores de esa columna, que cumplen las condiciones demandada por la query.

Es decir, me da un valor único.

Answer (score 0):

Si estás con la versión mayor a MySQL 8.0:

```sql
SELECT pm.id,
       pm.id_measurement,
       SUM(m.measurement_price_total_awarded)
         over (
           PARTITION BY pm.id_measurement
           ORDER BY pm.id, pm.id_measurement)
FROM   purchase_measurement AS pm
       inner join measurement AS m
               ON m.id = pm.id_measurement
       inner join purchase AS p
               ON p.id = pm.id_purchase
WHERE  p.id_purchase_status = 6
GROUP BY pm.id, pm.id_measurement, m.measurement_price_total_awarded
ORDER  BY ` pm `.` id_measurement ` DESC
```

Comment: Tengo una versión inferior, buscaré la forma de adaptarla.

Answer (score 0):

Al final me he dado cuenta que no podría sumar el lote completo y agruparlo mediante id, ya que es diferente para cada uno de ellos.

lo que hice fue agrupar por id_measurement y sumé aquellos que contenga el mismo id_measurement.

```
SELECT 
       pm.id_measurement,
       SUM(m.measurement_price_total_awarded)
FROM   purchase_measurement AS pm
       inner join measurement AS m
               ON m.id = pm.id_measurement
       inner join purchase AS p
               ON p.id = pm.id_purchase
WHERE  p.id_purchase_status = 6
AND  m.measurement_price_total_awarded IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY  pm.id_measurement, m.measurement_price_total_awarded  
ORDER BY `pm`.`id_measurement`  DESC;
```

[image: resultado_final]

Comment: No olvides aceptar tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Por cierto, evita colocar imágenes de datos que son texto. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.